# Newline is missing in flatfile

Tags: biztalk

I have created a flatfile schema in biztalk an my problem is that on tha last row in the resulting file the  "newline" is missing, I've done some reseach and found that  the record info should look something like this:

```
:recordInfo structure="delimited" delimiter_type="hex" delimiter_value="0x0D 0x0A" field_order="postfix" append_newline="yes" skip_CR="no" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x09" child_order="infix" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
```

But it still doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please put at least a little effort into writting and formating your question.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more readable. I'm not quite sure if your code is as your want it. Do you want it to start with `:recordInfo`?

Comment: flat file schemas are extremely difficult to get working correctly. Several times I've ended up doing something externally to get it working just because it was easier than the alternative. Sorry I don't have a better answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the child_order from "infix" to "postfix". This is telling all the lines end with a newline character (even if its the last line). 
If its "infix" then it means all the lines are separated by the newline character between them i.e. not the last line.

Your newline character is defined by [delimiter_value="0x0D 0x0A"]. Also try changing this to just CR or CRLF or LF based on your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

What "new line" is varies between systems.

On Windows system it is char(13) and char(10) on other systems it is just char(13). So if you open a file from another system it can look as if the "new line" is missing.

Your definition is char(13) char(10)

```
Child Delimiter: 0x0D 0x0A
```

This might not match your file, you may need to change to this:

```
Child Delimiter: 0x0A
```

for details see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline